# fetchColumn() not saving result to variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So the query I am running can have 0, 1, or many results. I need to store the number of rows in a query to a variable. Using PDO I should be able to do that using the `fetchColumn()` method. But it is not givng ANY result. When I echo out `$numrows` I am getting nothing, not even a zero. I know it is probably something really small but I have been staring at this code for an hour now and I need a fresh set of eyes guys.

```
    try {
        $count = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM location WHERE location.zip = :input');
        $count->bindValue(':input', $input);
        $numrows = $count->fetchColumn();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Problem on MySQL PDO interaction - error message passed
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: You never execute the prepared statement.

Comment: I shouldn't have to, the `fetchColumn()` method would do that for me.

Comment: Where does it say fetchColumn executes a  query?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I guess another piece of my code works for another reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add just after binding the values, before `fetchColumn()`:

```
$count->execute();
```